# Unity3D/AnimationRigging - Rig not a child Transform in the Animator hierarchy

Tags: unity, animation, rigging

I'm using Animation Rigging in Unity and was having some success until I realized my rig was built on the wrong GameObject. This was causing the Animator on the character to be overridden by the animator that Animation Rigging "Rig Setup" created.

I moved the `Rig Builder` component onto the `Character` GameObject that already had the `Animator` set up, but now every single rig component is causing an error. I've completely recreated the rig and all of the constraints, but still get the same error.

For example: "Could not resolve  'Character/Rig_HandIK/LeftHandIK'  because it is not a child Transform in the Animator hierarchy". `Character` is the GO with `Animator` & `Rig Builder` components, `Rig_HandIK` is a child of `Character` with a `Rig` component, and `LeftHandIK` is a child of Rig_HandIK which has the `Two Bone IK Constraint` component.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. While the rig gameobjects were children of the Animator, they were not siblings of the body mesh & armature. Moving them all into the same gameobject fixed the issue.

Comment: I spent hours on this issue and this saved my day. Cheers!